# Finding cell in another column associated with max value in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Say my structure is this:

```
A    B
1    0.1
2    0
5    42
4    7
```

And in cell C1 I want the value in B that is associated with the maximum value in column A - in this case 42.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 =VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

That is: *"lookup the maximum value if column A in the table of columns A to B and return the value in the second column"*

Comment: Works for the structure I posted but if I have a column in between and try =VLOOKUP(MAX(C:C),A:C,1,FALSE), it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: The 3rd parameter is the column reference - so if the table you're looking at is columns `A:C` (A to C) then 1 would refer to column A, 2 to B, 3 to C, so the 3rd parameter should be a 3 instead of 1.